# How to use timeout in a command that reads only a specific reply in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to create a quiz bot in discord. I have asked a similar question a few days ago, but turns out I still need more understanding about this topic. This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def ask(ctx):
    quiz_data = {
        'question_1': (["1", "One"], "one"),
        'question_2': (["2", "Two"], "two"),
    }
    question = random.choice(list(quiz_data.keys()))
    answers, hint = quiz_data[question]

    await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(question)

    def check_sender(msg): 
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    def check_answer(msg):
        return any(answer in msg.content for answer in answers) 

    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender, timeout=10)
        if check_answer(msg):
            await ctx.send("good")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send(f"What is the answer to this question? hint: {hint}")
        await ctx.send(question)

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender, timeout=None)
        if check_answer(msg):
            await ctx.send("good")
        else: 
            await ctx.send("wrong.")
```

This is the concept i'm currently using for the bot. Note that this whole code works without errors. The main problem here is that once you send a wrong answer, the command simply ends. I assume its because of the fact there is no else statement  under the try function (?), but I couldn't think of anything to pass under it. I did get this code from asking about it before but it did not actually answer my question. Is there any way to create a code where the bot continues the timeout even though a user sends a wrong answer?

Sorry if I didn't explain it well enough or if the title is not fit, I'll be glad to answer any questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a while loop, to have a "shared" cooldown you're gonna need to use `async_timeout.timeout` (it’s a dependency of a dependency of discord.py so it should already be installed)

```py
from async_timeout import timeout


@client.command()
async def ask(ctx):
    quiz_data = {
        'question_1': (["1", "One"], "one"),
        'question_2': (["2", "Two"], "two"),
    }
    question = random.choice(list(quiz_data.keys()))
    answers, hint = quiz_data[question]

    await ctx.send("What is the answer to this question?")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(question)

    def check_sender(msg): 
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    def check_answer(msg):
        return any(answer in msg.content for answer in answers) 

    
    try:
        async with timeout(10):
            while True:
                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_sender)
                if check_answer(msg):
                    await ctx.send("good")
                    break  # exiting out of the loop if the answer is correct
                else:
                    await ctx.send("wrong. Try again")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("timeout is over")
```

Comment: i also thought about that, but then the timeout would reset after each (wrong) answer if i am right

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You want a "shared" cooldown for all the questions?

Comment: I think he does, at least that's what I would conclude from "`Is there any way to create a code where the bot continues the timeout even though a user sends a wrong answer?`"

Comment: Yes, that's my bad. Editing the answer

Comment: Hello @ŁukaszKwieciński thank you so much! The code is working perfectly. But I want to ask if there is any way to have the bot not say anything if a user gives the wrong answer? I don't  think users have to know they got the wrong answer until the bot sends a message that user is right. I currently am using a print statement under the else but I want to ask if there is any alternative. Thanks!

Comment: No need to put the else part at all, it’s not obligatory to have it

Comment: All right @ŁukaszKwieciński, thanks so uch for your help~!